# Public interface deriving from internal?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, public, internal

An assembly exposes several interfaces (`IFirst`, `ISecond`, `IThird`) to the outside world, i.e. those interfaces are `public`.

Now, as an implementation detail, all of these objects share a common characteristic, described by interface `IBase`. I do not want to make `IBase` public, as this may change in future implementations and is completely irrelevant for the users of my assembly.

Obviously, a public interface cannot derive from an internal one (gives me a compiler error).

Is there any way to express that `IFirst`, `ISecond`, and `IThird` have something in common from an internal point of view only?

Answer (score 4):

Not in C#

The best you can do is have your *classes* implement both internal and public interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew said above. Just to expand, here's a code sample:

```
public interface IFirst
{
    string FirstMethod();
}

public interface ISecond
{
    string SecondMethod();
}

internal interface IBase
{
    string BaseMethod();
}

public class First: IFirst, IBase
{
    public static IFirst Create()  // Don't really need a factory method;
    {                              // this is just as an example.
        return new First();
    }

    private First()  // Don't really need to make this private,
    {                // I'm just doing this as an example.
    }

    public string FirstMethod()
    {
        return "FirstMethod";
    }

    public string BaseMethod()
    {
        return "BaseMethod";
    }
}

public class Second: ISecond, IBase
{
    public static ISecond Create()  // Don't really need a factory method;
    {                               // this is just as an example.
        return new Second();
    }

    private Second()  // Don't really need to make this private,
    {                 // I'm just doing this as an example.
    }

    public string SecondMethod()
    {
        return "SecondMethod";
    }

    public string BaseMethod()
    {
        return "BaseMethod";
    }
}
```